# Sequential Number Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress

I managed to get the info needed to create sequential number for CF7 through https://www.banna360.com/contact-from7-dynamic-number-generation/

```
function wpcf7_generate_rand_number( $wpcf7_data ) {
    $properties = $wpcf7_data->get_properties();
    $shortcode = '[rand-generator]';
    $mail = $properties['mail']['body'];
    $mail_2 = $properties['mail_2']['body'];

    $subject = $properties['mail']['subject'];
    $subject2 = $properties['mail_2']['subject'];

    if( preg_match( "/{$shortcode}/", $mail ) || preg_match( "/[{$shortcode}]/", $mail_2 ) ) {
        $option = 'wpcf7sg_' . $wpcf7_data->id();
        $sequence_number = (int)get_option( $option ) + 1;
        update_option( $option, $sequence_number );
        $properties['mail']['body'] = str_replace( $shortcode, $sequence_number, $mail );
        $properties['mail_2']['body'] = str_replace( $shortcode, $sequence_number, $mail_2 );
        $properties['mail']['subject'] = str_replace( $shortcode, $sequence_number, $subject );
        $properties['mail_2']['subject'] = str_replace( $shortcode, $sequence_number, $subject2 );

        $wpcf7_data->set_properties( $properties );
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_generate_rand_number' );
```

However, I need to specify a start number (eg. 1000001) instead of just starting from 1. Any idea how I do that with this code?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your "start number" in this code? Is it "$sequence_number" ?

Comment: "Start number" should be (int)get_option( $option ) in $sequence_number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sequence_number = (int)get_option( $option ) + 1;
if ($sequence_number == 1) {
    $sequence_number = 1000001;
}
update_option( $option, $sequence_number );
```

Comment: That only works for the first number, and then it goes back to 2 instead of 1000002. It needs to continue on with the sequence.

Comment: The update_option($option, $sequence_number) should immediately update the option in the db to 1000001 so that next time, it will be 1000001 and hence will only add 1 to it. Have you tried it?